# Access SQL Server 2008 R2 database from netbeans 8

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, netbeans, database-connection

I am completely new to java, and I want to make a connection to a remote SQL server 2008 R2 database (like 192.168.17.11) and load data from it.
 Please suggest alternative ways if you know any.

Comment: Whay are you registering a MySQL connection when you want to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: OMG! I didnt notice that. I'll change the question. Thanks for pointing out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must have JDBC driver for MS SQL, you have two jars (jtds-1.2.5.jar or sqljdbc4-2.0.jar), which added to your classpath

Second you need to create your connection as below:

```
String password="pass";
String driver= "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"; // For sqljdbc4, use: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
String username="user";
String URL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://serverIP:port/dbname"; // For sqljdbc4, use: jdbc:sqlserver://serverIP:port;databaseName=dbname
Class.forName(driver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);

// Use your connection here
// Don't forget to close the connection
```

Comment: How can i get to show the databases in the services tab by using add a new connection? the two files were:
sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar
Also how do I add them to the classpath?

Comment: From services tab, new database, new driver add your driver jar and fill database properties and then finish

Comment: Try this link [Netbean IDE Databases](https://netbeans.org/features/ide/database.html)